# flutter dart: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an error here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './answer.dart';
import './question.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final VoidCallback answerQuestion;
  Quiz(
      {required this.questions,
      required this.questionIndex,
      required this.answerQuestion});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Question((questions[questionIndex]['questionText']) as String),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text'] as String);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

here is an error:

```
answer['score']
```

Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra arguments.dart[extra_positional_arguments](https://dart.dev/diagnostics/extra_positional_arguments)

Type: `String`

View Problem (Alt+F8)

Comment: use Function answerQuestion;  for any function to pass between screen .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`answerQuestion` is of type `VoidCallback` which means a function without arguments or return data. But you are calling it with an argument. You can change this

```
final VoidCallback answerQuestion;
```

to this

```
final Function(dynamic) answerQuestion;
```

to resolve the error

Comment: super.you are amazing